# Newer package from repository of other Ubuntu version

Tags: 14.04, repository, official-repositories

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Is there any simple way to install newer version of package from newer version repository?

I tried this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

But this method seems to be able make mess in system when used wrong and it doesn’t work for me.

PS: It's this package http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libav-tools&searchon=names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinning won't preference a *newer* version; Apt does that by default. Pinning is only for sticking on older versions.

If you've added a newer repo that contains a newer version of a package, and `apt update; apt dist-upgrade` doesn't upgrade it, chances are the repo isn't providing updates for your release of Ubuntu (eg 14.04). Visit the PPA's Launchpad page and check the releases it supports.

There isn't a universal solution for this. For some [small] things, you can edit the sources configuration (in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...`) and change `trusty` to whatever release it is that's supported ***but*** that often isn't safe.

You may be in the position of needing to build it yourself.

Comment: If I just add repo from vivid, for example, and try to upgrade, it won't upgrade all packages, not only one?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about PPAs (which only tend to deal with a few packages at a time), not an entire release repository. Don't add those, even with pinning.

Comment: I could just download newer package and try install it by dpkg, but then I will need to download ([from there](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libav-tools)) and install all dependencies (probably like 50 packages) manual. That is why I wanted to automate it by repository. So PPA is only reasonable way to get newer packages in simple (for beginners) way?

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**